# Two submit buttons in redux form React

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

Before someone refers me to another post or flags this as 'duplicate' I've already tried every solution I've found and nothing works. So, hopefully someone can shed some light on this because I am completed baffled as to how to even do this.

I have a redux form in a Laravel / React project but I need to have an additional button as well as Submit for saving the form for later (i.e. part filled). Both `onClick` attributes point to a `handleSubmit` function in the parent component but the difference is, an `isDraft` flag is set differently depending on what button was used to submit. Currently the behaviour I'm getting is that the Submit button works fine but the Save For Later button does nothing.

Here's my buttons:

```
<Button
    disabled={ submitting }
    type="button"
    onClick={ () => handleSubmit(onSubmit) }>
    Submit Application
</Button>

<Button
    disabled={ submitting }
    type="button"
    onClick={ () => handleSubmit(onSaveForLater) }>
    Save for Later
</Button>
```

Here's a stripped down version of the module included in the parent component:

```
<MyForm
    initialValues={ application }
    isSaving={ this.state.isSaving }
    onSubmit={ (params) => this._onSubmit(params) }
    onSaveForLater={ (params) => this._onSaveForLater(params) }
/>
```

The `_onSubmit()` and `_onSaveForLater()` functions are pretty much the same (they just call a save function in the repo), except a different value for `isDraft` is passed in the params each time.

```
const mergedParams = {
    ...params,
    isDraft: true,
    id: this.props.params.id
};
```

Like I say, clicking the Submit button works fine, but the Save For Later button does nothing. Is there something I'm missing here? I am not an expert in redux form and I can't really find a conclusive solution - is this even possible?

Comment: Are you using the `redux-form` library here? If not, you should use just the `redux` tag.

Comment: This question needs a [mcve]. We don't know what `handleSubmit`, `params` and `this` is referring to in your code snippets.

Comment: `this` means it's within the component. `params` is the URL parameters (so, the id passed in the URL) and the form values, and `handleSubmit` is a redux form submit trigger. There is really nothing complicated about these, if you are familiar with react and redux-form.

Comment: Yes I am using redux-form as stated in the question...